# Flat rate shipping without applying exchange rate

Tags: shipping, currency, multicurrency

We have a magento setup with multiple sites/stores, each with a different currency.

It is setup to use a global base currency so that product prices will be updated as the exchange rates change.

HOWEVER, since the flat rate shipping is applied on the website level, we would like the shipping prices to be as we set them in the local currency of the site/store, as opposed to the global base currency.

For example, base currency is USD
Shipping in Canada is $3.99 CAD, but shows up as $5.25 CAD (basically assuming the $3.99 is in USD and multiplying by the exchange rate).  Short of updating the shipping prices whenever the currency changes (which is unreasonable), what can be suggested to keep the shipping price in the local store currency and not the global currency?

Comment: Hi, have you ever found a solution to your answer? We are having the same problem.